# Why will try() or tryCatch() not work here?

Tags: r, exception, try-catch

R dataframe, this instance is missing the column that COULD exist and i may need to parse, "V3".

```
a <- "\\somefilepath"
b <- "some_string"
V1 <- "string to parse"
V2 <- "string to parse"
Read_3 <- '("0","0")'

runlinks <- data.frame(a,b,V1,V2,Read_3)
runlinks
```

Some rows, do not have data in certain columns (V3 column here).

I need to use the column that may or may not exist(V3), and try to pull info out of the $V3 string if it does exist. For instances where it exists it works fine, but I need functionality for those instances where that column will not be there for extraction. In that scenario, I have pre-populated the column in the dataframe.

When the data does not exist for a certain instance, I want the line to be skipped, and processing to continue. Preferrably, line would contain the pre-populated value.

Because I am running the R script in a .bat file, any errors will close the program and need to be avoided.

I'm trying to use str_extract_all() on a column that may or may not exist(depending on the raw data) and I would like the script to continue to the next line *if* that column is missing because of bad data. However, I cannot get try() or tryCatch to work in this instance. I keep getting assignment errors...

```
runlinks$Read_3 <- tryCatch(str_extract_all(runlinks$V3, pattern = "\\d+"[[1]]), error = function(e) runlinks$Read_3 <- NULL)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Read_3, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
OR
runlinks$Read_4 <- try(str_extract_all(runlinks$V4, pattern = "\\d+"[[1]]))
 "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Read_4, value = list()) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1"
```

Typically I can use try(), just skips to next line, or tryCatch(x , function(e) NULL) and get it to either replace with NULL(or whatever replacement value). I am trying to figure out, why it will not working here and I keep getting assignment errors.

For tryCatch(), I have also tried NA, "NA", and what I really want to replace with, list(c(0,0)) after function(e) for replacement.

Comment: I also wanted to add, that it doesn't matter if the column pre-exists or not, throwing same error.

Comment: your example does not work: There is no `runlinks` in your example, and no `V3` column in your `df`

Comment: DF name has been changed. it was just to show the structure. V3 DOES NOT EXIST PER THE PROBLEM. V3 CAN or CANNOT exist. I have an issue, where if it DOES NOT EXIST, my try will not allow the script to continue. I need to get it to run on an exmape where V3 does not exist in the dataframe.